# yii2 sorting is not working

Tags: sorting, yii2

i want to sort the data fetched using id, i want to do it from controller but it's not working with both asc and desc,where i'm doing mistake? I hope someone can help me,thanks in advance

```
public function actionIndex()
    {  
        $userid =  Yii::$app->User->id;
        $searchModel = new UservdoSearch();
        $video= new ActiveDataProvider(
        ['query'=>Uservdo::find()->where('user_id=:uid',['uid'=>$userid])],**['sort' =>['defaultOrder'=>['id'=>SORT_DESC]]]**
        );

         return $this->render('index', [
               'model' => $searchModel,'dataProvider'=>$video
      ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use 'sort' as an array element   remove ['sort'......] with 'sort'....

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {  
          $userid =  Yii::$app->User->id;
          $searchModel = new UservdoSearch();
          $video= new ActiveDataProvider(
          ['query'=> Uservdo::find()->where('user_id=:uid',['uid'=>$userid]),
           'sort' => ['defaultOrder'=>['id'=>SORT_DESC]],
          );

           return $this->render('index', [
                 'model' => $searchModel,'dataProvider'=>$video
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: i have tried this before itself ,and it will give a syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')'

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer bro,it should be inside query.thanks for your help.Answer is,`['query'=>Uservdo::find()->where('user_id=:uid',['uid'=>$userid]),'sort' =>['defaultOrder'=>['id'=>SORT_DESC]]]`